# Why Would Date Change give me This Error Code?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have this code that connect to an API. It uses the current month and year to do a query of data. When the month was Aug, and it used the number 8 for ${month}, all worked perfectly.  Now that it is Sept, and it uses 9 for ${month}, it returns "request failed with status 400".  But if I set it back to 8, it works perfectly again. Any idea why this would be the case?

Getting Date and Setting Path based on date:

```
 const date = new Date();
  console.log(date);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const path =  `/v2/reports/time/team?from=${year}0${month}01&to=${year}0${month}31`;
```

Then this call, worked perfectly throughout the month of Aug, when month was 8.  Now in Sept, month changes to 9, and I get status 400.  Why?

Variables for API call:

```
const https = require('https');
  const options = {
    protocol: "https:",
    hostname: "api.xxxxx.com",
    path: path,
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "PPR Profile",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + "xxxxxxxxx",
      "Harvest-Account-ID": "xxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
```

Actual Call:
When I manually set month to 8, console log shows exactly the data I want.  When manually set month to 9, i get the error 400 code.

```
let teamBillableData = [];
  let teamMemberBillableAmount = 0;
  let teamMemberIndex = 0;

  https.get(options, (res) => {
            const { statusCode } = res;

            if (statusCode !== 200) {
                console.error(`Request failed with status: ${statusCode}`);
                return;
            }

            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let rawData = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                    for (let i = 0; i < parsedData.results.length; i++){
                        console.log(`${parsedData.results[i].user_name} billable: $${parsedData.results[i].billable_amount}`);
                    }
                  console.log(parsedData.results);
```

Comment: How many days does September have, e.g., compared to August?

Answer (score 0):

As Dave hints at, your API may require valid dates. There are only 30 days in September and your end date is set to 31 for all requests.

You will also need to fix where the code appends 0 to the month as it will create three digit months for October, November, and December.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I do actually have a conditional to handle the 2 digit vs 1 digit months.  I just hid for simplicity here.  So I need to make another conditional based on how many days each month has.  Ok.  Thanks.